# Can't retrieve last token from a file buffer

Tags: c, c89

I wrote some code that reads a text file and and loads each line into a buffer. That buffer is then processed using the strtok() function with "," as the delimiter. I retrieve the first 3 tokens just fine, but I can't get the last token. This is the first time I've run across this. On the last strtok() call when I should get the pointer to the last token, strtok() returns null.

Partial Code:

```
   for(j = 0, token = strtok(buffer, del); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, del), j++) {
            printf("j: %d, token: %s\n",j, token);
            switch(j) {
                case 0:
                    index = fnv1aHash(token, (reqdata_len-1));
                    t_indices[i] = index;
                    addNode(&(table[index]));
                    table[index][0].course = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(token));
                    strcpy(table[index][0].course, token);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    table[index][0].category = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(token));
                    strcpy(table[index][0].category, token);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    strcpy(prereqbuff, token);
                    addPrereqs(prereqbuff, &(table[index][0].prereqs));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    table[index][0].notes = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(token));
                    strcpy(table[index][0].notes, token);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The switch statement is just to control what stuff goes where in a struct that organizes the line info by columns (delimited by the commas). So a sample line would look like:

```
Words words,Wordswords,Words,Words\n // (where \n represents a new line)
```

I've tried adding \n as a delimiter, but it didn't help. I don't even get inside "case 3:" since token points to null.

**FINAL EDIT**

I figured out my problem. addPrereqs() calls strtok within itself, and of course this means that messes up my original call to strtok in my main function. I read that one can use strtok_r() as a workaround. Ultimately I called strtok() once again right before I call addPrereqs() and used that token right away for what I originally wanted it. Relevant section of the code is below:

```
for(j = 0, token = strtok(buffer, del); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, del), j++) {
    switch(j) {
        case 0:
            index = fnv1aHash(token, (reqdata_len-1));
            t_indices[i] = index;
            addNode(&(table[index]));
            table[index][0].course = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(token));
            strcpy(table[index][0].course, token);
            break;
        case 1:
            table[index][0].category = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(token));
            strcpy(table[index][0].category, token);
            break;
        case 2:
            strcpy(prereqbuff, token);
            token = strtok(NULL, del);
            table[index][0].notes = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(token));
            strcpy(table[index][0].notes, token);
            addPrereqs(prereqbuff, &(table[index][0].prereqs));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [self-contained example program](/help/mcve) that we can run directly.

Comment: Why do you have `i++` at the bottom of the code block and not as part of the `for(i ...` statement?

Comment: Because comment lines aren't counted. I skip any comments in the file using `if(buffer[0] == '#') { continue;}`

Answer (score 3):

This `calloc(strlen(token), sizeof(char));` is the problem,

1. Don't use `calloc()` if you will overwrite the zeroes immediately.
2. More importantly, you need 1 more byte to store a string.

   ```
   table[index][0].notes = malloc(1 + strlen(token));
   ```

   in your code, `strcpy()` is writing the terminating `'\0'` to an illegal location, which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: And is there **any** extant system that doesn't have `strdup()`?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to use `strdup()` with the MSVC compiler, it requires macros like `#define strdup _strdup` how dumb is that? But it is so. The compiler would tell you that you should not use the `POSIX` names.

Comment: Initially table[index][0].notes doesn't have anything it's just a null char*. So i think the use of calloc vs malloc in this case is inconsequential. I see your point about the length though. Although, my real issue is my loop never gets to that section of code because strtok() doesn't return the last token it should, instead it returns null and exits.

Comment: There is no problem because of using `calloc()` but you don't need to, it could hide memory bugs from memory debuggers, when your code fails to initialize something and it did initialize it anyway.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Suggest posting your `strdup()` question.

Comment: @DamianJ you should post the rest of the function, i.e what is `del`? And I think it could be easy to parse that line of text with `strchr()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a minimal compilable example of your code (from the details posted) and there is simply nothing wrong with it - as posed in the question. It extracts all the tokens. I would criticise though, the cack-handed way it is put together - a horrible blend of `for` and implied `while` and `switch`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int j;
    char *token;
    char buffer[] = "Words words,Wordswords,Words,Words\n";
    char del[] = ",\n";
    for(j = 0, token = strtok(buffer, del); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, del), j++) {
            printf("j: %d, token: %s\n",j, token);
            switch(j) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
j: 0, token: Words words
j: 1, token: Wordswords
j: 2, token: Words
j: 3, token: Words
```

Comment: Yeah I tried to isolate it, but I couldn't reproduce it outside of my function. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Well now you've just added a load of stuff including presumably the extra 1 required for memory allocation that @iharob recommended, does that now cancel the question?